# 2d array of actionListeners and 2d arry of JButton trouble

Tags: java, arrays, jbutton

I'm having a little bit of trouble getting my actionListeners with my Jbuttons... So I have 3 files - one for the model (information storage), one for the actual GUI, and then a third that deals with all the actions to the buttons. In my GUI, i made a 8 by 8 array of JButtons with icons, each equipped with a selectedIcon as well. Then, in my controller class, I set the action listeners for all my buttons.. How do I properly set and use them for the 2D array of JButtons? I used a double for loop to make the grid.. and for the controller class, here is the code for the action listener that I have now:

```
for (i = 0; i < model.ROWS; i ++) {
  for (j = 0; j < model.ROWS; j ++) {

    buttonListeners[i][j] = new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        view.buttonGrid[i][j].setSelected(!view.buttonGrid[i][j].isSelected());
      }
    };
  }
}
i = 0;
j = 0;
enableListeners();
```

What it does now though is when i click any button, it only selects and deselects the first button... Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: It might be related to scopes of i and j in the anonymous class. So what do you think the values of i and j are when actionPerformed is actually CALLED? Try to get rid of that anonymous class.

Comment: Please format your code better. Too much white space makes it hard to read. You want it to be not too much, not too little. It's somewhat of an art to do it read, but read up on code formatting recommendations and try to emulate good programs from your books and tutorials.

Comment: I've tried to fix it just now for you, but in the future, please put in the little bit of effort to do this yourself. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you Hovercraft. It was my first try posting here, so I was a bit unsure with the formatting, but I think I have it now. I will try my best to have better formatting in the future.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to use the variables `i` and `j` in the `ActionListener` that you are creating there, the variables either have to be `final`, or instance variables of the enclosing class.

At the moment, they are abviously declared as instance variables. And after the action listeners have been created, you set them back to `i=0` and `j=0`. That's why all action listeners only affect `buttonGrid[0][0]`!

You can define local final variables for your purpose:

```
for (int i = 0; i < model.ROWS; i ++) 
{
    for (int j = 0; j < model.ROWS; j ++)
    {
        final int fi = i;
        final int fj = j;
        buttonListeners[i][j] = new ActionListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                view.buttonGrid[fi][fj].setSelected(
                    !view.buttonGrid[fi][fj].isSelected());
            }
        };
    }
}
```

(and don't forgest to remove the instance variables `i` and `j`, you should not need them any more)